# event control except as first statement of always block not supported

Tags: verilog

My code is here:
///////////////////////////////

```
module edge_wait(
    input wire enable,
    input  wire clk,
    output reg trigger
    );

   always @(posedge enable)
  begin
       trigger <=0;
       repeat (10) 
           begin
            @ (posedge clk);
            end
       trigger <=1;     
 end      
endmodule
```

///////////////////////////
when I run synthesis, I got the error "event control except as first statement of always block not supported ". How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Haii!!

You must note that delays (regular or timing based) are not supported in RTL coding.
(RTL means synthesizeable i.e., the code can be implemented on hardware)

Your code will simulate but do not get synthesized.(Will give the error you specified)

Try removing the @(posedge clk) inside your block. You won't get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn this into a state-machine/counter

```
module edge_wait(
    input wire enable,
    input  wire clk,
    output reg trigger
    );
integer counter
  always @(posedge clk)
     if (enable) begin
       trigger <= 0;
       counter <=0;
     end
     else if (counter == 10)
         trigger <= 1;
     else
         counter <= counter + 1;
endmodule
```

This assumes `enable` is treated like a synchronous reset. You will need to modify it to deal with behavior you did not specify, like what happens if enable goes high multiple times while the counter is counting.